# Codeigniter, HMVC : MX_Router is never called, resulting in 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I'm using codeigniter 2.1.3. 
I noticed a nice module called HMVC (Hierarchical MVC), which allows MVC development in a hierarchical manner, as the name indicates. So i downloaded it and installed it.

However, after doing the manipulations explained in every tutorial available, i get a 404 error when trying to access the test page that i created.

After searching for a while without success, i decided to install the latest version of codeigniter (2.2.0). I followed the tutorial, and it worked.

I decided to try to compare the 2 versions (the one that works, and the who which doesn't) to see which sources were called, and what seemed to fail in my codeigniter v2.1.3.

I found out that in my version 2.1.3 of codeigniter, the error happens because in function _validate_request of class /system/core/Router.php, the program reaches the end of the function because it hasn't found a controller class matching the URI (in this case localhost/codeigniter/users : it is suppose to detect that i have a module called users, and it should use the controller in application/modules/users to load the page). So the program reaches the function show_404() (see below) and generates a 404 error :

```
    // If we've gotten this far it means that the URI does not correlate to a valid
    // controller class.  We will now see if there is an override
    if ( ! empty($this->routes['404_override']))
    {
        $x = explode('/', $this->routes['404_override']);

        $this->set_class($x[0]);
        $this->set_method(isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');

        return $x;
    }

    // Nothing else to do at this point but show a 404
    show_404($segments[0]);
```

When checking what happens in version 2.2.0 (the one that works), another type of router class is used : application/third_party/MX/Router.php (instead of the default /system/core/Router.php).

I have the application/third_party/MX/Router.php installed.

So basically, my issue is that somehow, codeigniter doesn't instanciate the right Router.php file, but i don't understand what i've been doing wrong.

Can someone help?

Edit : i progressively migrated my site onto the version of codeigniter where HMVC works, while checking continuously if everything kept working. Everything worked until i migrated the file application/config/config.php. This must be a configuration issue after all.

Edit 2 : I didn't find the root cause of the issue. I ended up migrating the whole website on the new functionnal version of codeigniter, and it now works.